# Vertical cell alignment in Office UI Fabric grid

Tags: css, office-ui-fabric

Office UI Fabric offers a grid layout mechanism documented [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/layout). Column entries in a row (of class "ms-Grid-row") are of class "ms-Grid-col".

I cannot get the vertical alignment of a column entry to work properly, as all entries are always rendered with top alignment. From what I understand, the css property "align-items: center;" should do the trick, but it doesn't impact vertical alignment.

Is it possible to override vertical alignment to have all entries in a grid center-aligned ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see such option within the office UI CSS fabric, however, you can use the [**FLEX** CSS layout](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

For this approach, just use the `diplay:flex` **for the grid row** container, and add the additional **flex** rules according as the cheatsheet describes, so it vertically aligns any grid column that **row** containe could contain.

Example:

```
<div class="ms-Grid-row" style="display:flex">        
  <div class="ms-Grid-col  ms-sm6" >
    Content to be vertically aligned 1
  </div>
  <div class="ms-Grid-col  ms-sm6" >
    Content to be vertically aligned 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be answering this question too late. But I found the perfect way to do this:

Apply the following css to the grid row element (the parent to your ms-Grid-col):

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Reference: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/03/css-alignment/